# What information does Mode S provide?

Tags: transponder, tcas, mode-s

What information about own aircraft does TCAS Mode s( all call) send in the interrogation?

What information does Mode S transponder(intruder)replay to TCAS interrogation?

Comment: Are you looking for more information than [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_surveillance_radar#Mode_S) can provide?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/73264/62)

Answer (score 0):

Mode-S provides altitude and identification data, with Automatic Dependent Surveillance Broadcast (ADS-B) adding global navigation data typically obtained from a Global Positioning System (GPS) receiver. The position and identification data supplied by Mode S/ADS-B broadcasts are available to pilots and air traffic controllers.

Comment: If my ADS-B OUT in off,   then Mode S provides just altitude and identification (icao number)?

Comment: Yes. That's what it says in the answer.